# Deal with Multiple Summations

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Im just wondering why these are not equal. Here's a link to it written out on wolframaplha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(k%3D1)%5Ea+sum_(j%3D1)%5Eb+(2k%2Bj)+%3D+(2a%5E2%2Ab%2Bab%5E2%2B3ab)%2F2 Below is the input, I wasn't sure how to write it here. Thanks in advance :)
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0} ^a \sum_{j=0}^b (2k+j) = (2a^2b+ab^2+3ab)
\end{equation}

Comment: I suppose I'm left asking should they be equal? or why do you think they should be equal.

Comment: Well i thought they were equal, I got that using distribution, I know its wrong but i dont understand why and i dont know how to simplify it enough to get it to closed form

Comment: I think you wrote something wrong then. The equation you put in wolfram alpha and here doesn't fall from distribution of sum.

Comment: Where is the $+$ gone ?

Comment: With $n=1$, $(2\cdot0+0)+(2\cdot0+1)+(2\cdot1+0)+(2\cdot1+1)=6$, while $2((0+1)(0+1))=2$.

Comment: Grrr, silently changing the question is bad practice, it makes the comments and answers irrelevant.

Comment: sorry, i didnt want people to go to the effort of answering that question to realise i made a mistake

Comment: You should document the change.

Answer (score 2):

You can write

$$\sum_{k=0} ^n \sum_{j=0}^n (2k+j)=2\sum_{k=0} ^n \sum_{j=0}^n k+ \sum_{k=0} ^n \sum_{j=0}^n j=2(n+1)\sum_{k=0} ^n k+ (n+1)\sum_{j=0}^n j=3(n+1)\frac{n(n+1)}2.$$

Comment: would that work if the upper limits on the two summations are different? e.g. m and n

Comment: You have enough information to check by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm left to troubleshoot where you went wrong with this problem. First I'm not sure that it is immediately obvious that the two terms should be equal, one is the sum of $k,j$ the other is the product, sums are not products.

If you meant $\sum (2k\times j)$ then the two are equal.

If you meant $2\sum_k k+\sum_j j$ then the answer is that the sum over the other parameter gives a factor of $n+1$.

If you meant $2\sum_k \sum_j k+\sum_k \sum_j j$ then you will get equality.

If you want to evaluate these yourself it's pretty simple to do this starting at $\sum_{i=0} ^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\sum_{i=0} ^n i = (n+1)i$

Comment: sorry i made a mistake, I made up a simpler example of the question that i have to work out to try to understand the steps better. I used the distributive law without realising they were being added and not multiplied. this is the question I have to answer, show how you get to the RHS from the LHS. I dont know how to go about answering it any ideas? thanks a mill https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(k%3D1)%5Ea+sum_(j%3D1)%5Eb+(2k%2Bj)+%3D+(2a%5E2*b%2Bab%5E2%2B3ab)%2F2

Comment: I think that's derivable from the third suspected error, and the hint I gave you.

Comment: ok thanks a mill